# NSObject Is Being Created Twice

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsobject

I am using the following code to create a Session object and create and add the objects Exercise and Set to it.

But now I  have the problem of when I add an exercise to a custom date (chosen from UIDpatePicker and not today's date), it is  also automatically added to today's session as well.  Any ideas?

I think this is happening because when the view is loaded, it defaults to today's date and then creates  set, then when you add a set, it is being added to the custom date the user pics along with today's date.

Edit: I think its because the exercise is added to Session in the same method that the Session is created. So although the exercise may not have a set, the Session still has that exercise

```
- (void)createSession
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(timeStamp >= %@ && timeStamp <= %@)", targetDateBegins, targetDateEnds]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Session" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Fetch error: %@", error);

    if ([results count])
    {
        session = (Session *)[results objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    else
    {
        session = (Session *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Session" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        session.timeStamp = self.picker.date;
    }

    NSSet *filteredExercisesFromSession=[session.exercises filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"name == %@",selectedExerciseName]];
    if ([filteredExercisesFromSession count] > 0)
    {
        self.exercise=[filteredExercisesFromSession anyObject];
    }
    else
    {
        self.exercise = (Exercise *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        self.exercise.name = selectedExerciseName;
        [session addExercisesObject:exercise];
    }

    [fetchRequest release];
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    [setsTableView reloadData];
}

-(IBAction)createSet
{    
    Set *set = (Set *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Set" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    set.weight = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:weightSelected2];
    set.reps = [NSNumber numberWithInt:repSelected];
    set.timeStamp = self.picker.date;
    [self.exercise addSetsObject:set];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil; 
    [setsTableView reloadData];
}
```

Updated Code:

```
- (void)createSession
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *dateComponentsForToday = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:self.picker.date];
    [dateComponentsForToday setHour:0];
    [dateComponentsForToday setMinute:0];
    [dateComponentsForToday setSecond:0];
    NSDate *targetDateBegins = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponentsForToday]; 
    NSDate *targetDateEnds = [targetDateBegins dateByAddingTimeInterval:(60 * 60 * 24 - 1)];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(timeStamp >= %@ && timeStamp <= %@)", targetDateBegins, targetDateEnds]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Session" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
    NSLog(@"timeStamp >= %@ && timeStamp <= %@", targetDateBegins, targetDateEnds);

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Fetch error: %@", error);

    if ([results count])
    {
        session = (Session *)[results objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    else
    {
        session = (Session *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Session" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        session.timeStamp = self.picker.date;
    }

    NSSet *filteredExercisesFromSession = [session.exercises filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"name == %@",selectedExerciseName]];
    if ([filteredExercisesFromSession count] > 0)
    {
        self.exercise = [filteredExercisesFromSession anyObject];
    }

    [fetchRequest release];
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    [setsTableView reloadData];
}

-(IBAction)createSet
{    
    NSSet *filteredExercisesFromSession = [session.exercises filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"name == %@",selectedExerciseName]];

    if ([filteredExercisesFromSession count] > 0)
    {
        self.exercise = [filteredExercisesFromSession anyObject];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"exercise does not already exist");
        self.exercise = (Exercise *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        self.exercise.name = selectedExerciseName;
        self.exercise.muscleGroup = muscleName;
        [session addExercisesObject:exercise];
    }

    Set *set = (Set *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Set" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    set.weight = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:weightSelected2];
    set.reps = [NSNumber numberWithInt:repSelected];
    set.timeStamp = self.picker.date;
    [self.exercise addSetsObject:set];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil; 
    [setsTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I don't think, this solves you problem, but I think you should exchange the code 'self.exercise =' by 'exercise =' because of memory management.

Comment: Thanks Dasdom, so I should remove all instances of `self.exercise =` in these methods and keep just `exercise =` ?

Comment: Yes, I think so. You can also check the sample code on apples websites.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure that I understand your code, so I am possibly wrong...

What seems strange to me is this:

```
if ([results count])
{
    session = (Session *)[results objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

after doing a fetch based on timestamp, you get the first result; otherwise you initialize the session with `self.pickerDate`. Could be this the reason why you are adding the exercise to today's session?

EDIT:

In my mind, it is perfectly possible adding the exercise to the session in the same method where the session is created. What you say about the exercise being assigned to a Session but not to a Set could be the cause of internal inconsistency, but not of the fact that the exercise is added to today's session, unless there is some relationship between Sessions and Sets that is not evident (to me) from the code.

How do you define `targetDateBegins, targetDateEnds`? When createSession is called, those value determine if you create a new session or reuse an existing session. If you reuse an existing session, its date is already set and the picker is ignored.

A suggestion: set a break point at the start of `createSession` and debug your program, so that you can see exactly what happens in createSession and understand whether your expected path is being taken or the program does something that you did not expect.

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure.  I think the exercise is being added to today's session is because `createSession` is called by `viewDidLoad`.  Therefore, when the user selects the exercise from the previous tableview which loads this detail view we are dealing with, it initially defaults to today's date so the exercise is defaultly added to today's date on launch?

Comment: Wait, I think its because the exercise is added to Session in the same method that the Session is created.  So although the exercise may not have a set, the Session still has that exercise.

Comment: Dear Sergio, I have been trying this all day and have finally come up with a code that when I select a custom date, and add an exercise to it, it only adds the exercise to that date and not to today's session.  However I am still getting a Session object for today by default with no exercise in it.  I will post the code in original question.

Comment: I'm thinking now I can just check before I save the MOC that if the session for today's date has no exercises, delete it.  That may be a quick workaround to the problem.